# How to implement a validating constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: validation, constructor, kotlin, builder

I'm implementing vars in Kotlin that could receive out-of-bounds input from certain of their users.  I'd like to be able to optionally call (only on input from these untrusted users) a validating constructor that can return null, and then use the Elvis operator to specify defaults in the case of invalid input, as in:  `var myFoo = Foo.fromInt(i) ?: 1`.  I'm currently using a companion object method to validate the input:

```
open class Foo(val x:Int) {   // relies on valid x in 1..3
  companion object {
    fun fromInt(x: Int): Foo? = if (x in 1..3) Foo(x) else null
  }
}
class Bar(x:Int) : Foo(x)

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
  println(Foo.fromInt(2))    // Foo(2)
  println(Foo.fromInt(20))   // null
  // println(Bar.fromInt(2))
  // would like Bar(2) but as expected, companion isn't inherited
}
```

When I subclass `Foo`, I know I have to recreate the companion object.  I've tried inheriting the companion from an abstract class; however, the call to `Foo(x)` still points to `Foo` and not `Bar`, unless I override `fromInt` in each subclass' companion.  Is there a better or more Kotlin-idomatic way to deal with this kind of pattern of a validating constructor that can return `null` rather than creating the requested object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

could you simply use a single constructor and always validate its argument `x` and assign it to a property like here:

```
open class Foo (x: Int) {   // relies on valid x in 1..3
    val x: Int = if (x in 1..3) x else 1
}

class Bar(x: Int) : Foo(x)
```

Now calling the constructor with a value that is not in range, a default `Foo` is created, which is basically what you wanted to have I think. In my opinion it would be better if you threw a `IllegalArgumentException` instead of creating a default behind the scenes. What do you think?

Comment: I've tried that too.  The challenge is that `Foo` (in my app) is a type of field in a database, so there are 10+ fields of that type in each record, and some have different defaults upon validation failure.  Actually, even these 10+ could be grouped into a few groups, which was why I was trying to create subclasses `Bar`, `Baz` etc. to handle the different types of the same fundamental type `Foo`.  Even among `Bar`, `Baz`, etc., there's more than one of each in the record and each has different defaults.  That's why I thought null/Elvis might be a nice way to handle it... Any other options?

Comment: To your second point about `IllegalArgumentException`, I think that's my next best option.  In these cases though, failure **is expected** and will happen often.  I also didn't want to create a behind-the-scenes default... which is why I wanted to expose the applied `?: default` at the call site, but that requires an `orNull` secondary constructor for that to work.  90% of instantiations will the primary null-safe constructor, but the companion/secondary validating constructor would only by used for processing external input where failure is likely.  Open to other thoughts though...

Comment: Regarding other options: in that case I’d make the validation abstract so that the subclasses have to provide the rules which can be used in the validation during construction.

Comment: How will it be if the class is a data class ?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the init block as well as [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html).

```
open class Foo(val x:Int) {
  init {
    require(x in 1..3) {
      "relies on valid x in 1..3"
    }
  }
}
class Bar(x:Int) : Foo(x)
```

Example run:

```
>>> open class Foo(val x:Int) {
...   init {
...     require(x in 1..3) {
...       "relies on valid x in 1..3"
...     }
...   }
... }
>>> class Bar(x:Int) : Foo(x)
>>> val b = Bar(3)
>>> val b = Bar(4)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: relies on valid x in 1..3
    at Line_18$Foo.<init>(Line_18.kts:3)
    at Line_19$Bar.<init>(Line_19.kts:1)
>>> b.x
res22: kotlin.Int = 3
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also look for **"overloading invoke() function for constructor validation"**.

```
class Student private constructor(val rollNo: Int) {
companion object {
    operator fun invoke(rollNo: Int): Student {
        //Do your validation here
        if (rollNo < 1) {
            throw Exception() // or any default Student
        } else
            return Student(rollNo)
    }
}
```

}

```
val student1 =Student(4)
val student2 =Student(-1) // will throw exception
```

This approach hides the constructor(private) and because of the overloaded syntax it looks like we are making a constructor call .